# Prove that $4$ divides $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $a_1$,$a_2$,$a_3$,.......,$a_n$ be $n$ such that each $a_i$ either $1$ or $-1$.If

$a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4+a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5+......+a_n a_1 a_2 a_3=0$,

then prove that $4$ divides $n$.

I tried this for small n and also observed different specific cases such as $a_1=1$ $a_2=-1$ $a_3=1$ $a_4=-1$.... etc.

But I am unable to circumvent anyway. Any kind of hints and full answers will be appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this has been handled on our site recently. Not sure whether the duplicate had *contest-math* tag.

Comment: Found it - by simply Googling "a_1a_2a_3a_4 site:math.stackexchange.com"

Comment: [This is another duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1320964/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually it's more like a proof-explanation request than a duplicate. That's why I just posted a link in the comments without marking as a duplicate.

Comment: No accusations of copying were made! I simply closed this, because it has been asked and answered before. Happens often enough here, believe me :-). Closing duplicates is a site rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: When you change $a_r$ from $-1$ to $+1$ you change the value of four of the summands. Each summand which changes changes in value by $2$ - either from $+1$ to $-1$ or from $-1$ to $+1$. If you change all the $-1$ terms $a_r$ to $+1$ what happens to the sum?